# GIMP: exporting as .png does not produce an image with the specified dimensions in "Scale image" or "Print size"

Tags: gimp, png, image-quality, image-format

Let us say that I have a 600x600 pixels picture and I want to create a .png file with it that is 6x6 cm in size.
What I do is to set the following in "Image->Scale image":

[image]

I can check in "Image->Print Size" that my settings seem to be correct, since it tells that the image is 6x6 cm big:

[image]

If I export the image as a **.pdf file**, my pdf viewer (Evince) or other programs (like Inkscape) show it with the appropriate dimensions, namely 6x6 cm.
However, if I export it as a **.png file**, the dimensions change to approximately 17x17 cm.
Why does this happen and how can I solve it?

EDIT: the "Export As" options that I use are the default ones, where the "Save resolution" box is checked.

Comment: Do you have "Save Resolution" checked in the PNG export window?

Comment: Yes (added in EDIT).

Comment: Where exactly is the PNG showing dimensions of 17x17cm? If you open it back in GIMP what resolution does it show?

Comment: The resolution that it shows is the same as I set as an input (600x600 pixels and 100 pixels/cm). So far, so good. However, as I say, when I open the .png image with other programs (Inkscape, Evince), it is 17x17 cm in size.

Comment: Can you check the resolution somewhere other than in GIMP? The obvious answer to your question is that the PPI isn't being saved with the PNG correctly but I'm not sure how or why

Comment: I have checked the resolution of the .png image with another program (ImageMagick, as indicated [here](http://askubuntu.com/a/573685/471491)), and the result I get is the correct one: 600x600 pixels and 100 pixels/cm. Thus, the problem must be that both Evince and Inkscape open the image wrong. It is strange that they open the .pdf images perfectly well, though. Still confused about this issue.

Comment: Ah ok, yeh the problem is inkscape and Evince then. I'll post an answer now...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [Inkscape wiki FAQ](http://wiki.inkscape.org/wiki/index.php/Frequently_asked_questions#Why_do_images_.22grow.22_when_imported_into_Inkscape.3F):

> There is a limitation in the way Inkscape imports raster/bitmap images (e.g JPEG, PNG, TIFF images): it cannot read the image resolution. Inkscape assumes a 1-to-1 relation at 90dpi, so any imported image with a different resolution will appear to be scaled.

That explains the difference in size you are seeing:

600px at 90PPI = 16.93cm

I'm assuming there is a similar problem in Evince.